# Getting started on python triple quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple triple quote print statement. See below. For the OVER lineart, it gets truncated into two different lines (when you copy paste this into the interpreter.) But, if I insert a space or any at the end of each of the lines, then it prints fine. Any idea why this behavior in python.

I am inclined to think this is due to \ and / at the end of the lines, but I cannot find a concrete reason. I tried removing them and and have some observations but would like a clear reasoning..

```
print(
               """
                 _____       ____       __  __   ______
                / ____|     / _  |     / |  /|  |  ____|
               | |         / / | |    / /| /| | | |___
               | |   _    / /__| |   / / |_/| | |  ___|
               | |__| |  / /   | |  / /     | | | |____
                \_____/ /_/    |_| /_/      |_| |______|

                ______   _      _   ______   _____
               /  __  \ | |    / / |  ____| |  _  \
               | |  | | | |   / /  | |___   | |_| |
               | |  | | | |  / /   |  ___|  |  _  /
               | |__| | | |_/ /    | |____  | | \ \
               \______/ |____/     |______| |_|  \_\

                """
               )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have `\` backslash escapes in your string, one each on the last two lines as well as on the first line spelling *over*, all three part of the letter *R*. These signal to Python that you wanted to *ignore* the newline right after it.

Either use a space right after each `\` backslash at the end of a line, *double* the backslashes to escape the escape, or use a *raw* string by prefixing the triple quote with a `r`:

```
print(
               r"""
                 _____       ____       __  __   ______
                / ____|     / _  |     / |  /|  |  ____|
               | |         / / | |    / /| /| | | |___
               | |   _    / /__| |   / / |_/| | |  ___|
               | |__| |  / /   | |  / /     | | | |____
                \_____/ /_/    |_| /_/      |_| |______|

                ______   _      _   ______   _____
               /  __  \ | |    / / |  ____| |  _  \
               | |  | | | |   / /  | |___   | |_| |
               | |  | | | |  / /   |  ___|  |  _  /
               | |__| | | |_/ /    | |____  | | \ \
               \______/ |____/     |______| |_|  \_\

                """
               )
```

Raw strings don't support backslash escapes, except for escaped quotes (`\"` and `\'`) which would be included *with the backslash*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `\` at the end of line so you need to escape them. For that i use another backslash.

```
print(
           """
             _____       ____       __  __   ______
            / ____|     / _  |     / |  /|  |  ____|
           | |         / / | |    / /| /| | | |___
           | |   _    / /__| |   / / |_/| | |  ___|
           | |__| |  / /   | |  / /     | | | |____
            \_____/ /_/    |_| /_/      |_| |______|

            ______   _      _   ______   _____
           /  __  \ | |    / / |  ____| |  _  \\
           | |  | | | |   / /  | |___   | |_| |
           | |  | | | |  / /   |  ___|  |  _  /
           | |__| | | |_/ /    | |____  | | \ \\
           \______/ |____/     |______| |_|  \_\\

            """
           )
```